# How can I get the hash (or its TFS equivalent) of the current revision in TFS?

Tags: tfs

In Mercurial I did `hg tip` and voilà - I have the hash of the current revision. Knowing it anyone can locate the relevant source code precisely.

In TFS I tried this command:

```
C:\>tf.exe history /stopafter:1 /version:T /format:detailed /noprompt $/myprojects/V2/Root
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Changeset: 69017
User: YabaDabaDoo\YogiBear
Date: Wednesday, August 28, 2013 9:24:17 AM

Comment:
  Branched from $/Root

Items:
  branch $/myprojects/V2/Root


C:\>
```

And it is not what I am after. There were tons of code committed since the branch was created, I need the number of the most recent changeset present in the current directory. So that if someone later communicates this number back to me I will be able to locate the respective source code precisely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code shows the changeset of the *directory itself*.  If you want the latest changeset that affects the contents of the directory, you need to specify the `/recursive` option:

```
tf history /stopafter:1 /version:T /recursive /format:detailed /noprompt $/myprojects/V2/Root
```

If you want to know the version you have locally, you will want to query for the *workspace version* by using **`/version:W`**.

```
tf history /stopafter:1 /version:W /recursive /format:detailed /noprompt $/myprojects/V2/Root
```

More details on the syntax of this history command are available [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxtbh4yh.aspx) and Buck Hodges has an excellent [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2009/01/26/how-to-determine-the-latest-changeset-in-your-workspace.aspx) that covers a very similar scenario.

Comment: Can I instruct the command not to go to the server, but limit it to the latest changeset present locally, even if there are more on the server? I need to know the latest changeset corresponding to the actual code in the working directory, rather than that on the server (which may be newer)

Comment: One more question - can I get just the changeset? Without all the rest?